# Special characters in Extjs4?

Tags: extjs, indexing, special-characters, extjs4, utf

How to get special characters like ČĆŠĐŽ working in Extjs4. I have tried adding meta utf-8..., also tried with !DOCTYPE html5, and XHTML 1.0 Transitional. Prefered index.html on sencha web page is :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title id='title'>HTML Page setup Tutorial</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../resources/css/ext-all.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    </head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you get instead of the expected characters? Is your document actually UTF-8 encoded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my fault!! , didnt encode to utf, default to ANSI in notepad++, no need for META or DOCTYPE, **just encode in editor**... Thanks!