# Special character ExtJs 4

Tags: extjs4, special-characters

I have developed a small view that contains special char like 'é' and when I go to the browser I find that these special char have been replaced by question mark, I have added the meta tag with `charset="utf-8"` to my index to resolve the problem but no changes, this is the first time I encounter such a problem, because I have already developed other views with special char (for an other ExtJs project) without any problem. any idea about this ?

```
Ext.define('ALM.MyView', {
extend : 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    initComponent : function() {
    var me = this;

    Ext.applyIf(me, {
        items : [{
            xtype : 'toolbar',
            //padding: '10px 10px 10px 10px',
            //height: 28,
            //width: 714,

            items : [
                               {
                xtype : 'button',
                text : 'tout',
                iconCls : 'all-icon'
            }, {
                xtype : 'button',
                text : 'éffacer',
                iconCls : 'clear-icon'
            }, {
                xtype : 'tbseparator'
            }, {
                xtype : 'button',
                text : 'ajouter',
                iconCls : 'add-icon'
            }, {
                xtype : 'button',
                text : 'supprimer',
                iconCls : 'delete-icon'
            }, {
                xtype : 'button',
                text : 'modifier',
                iconCls : 'modify-icon'
            }, {
                xtype : 'button',
                text : 'rechercher',
                iconCls : 'find-icon'
            }
                     ]
          }]  
              });
     me.callParent(arguments);
        }
        });
```

**UPDATE**

This is what I get as HTML :

```
<span id="button-1006-btnInnerEl" class="x-btn-inner" style="">�����</span>
```

and for instance I get this in the view : (Toolbar)
[image]

Comment: What do you in your browser if you go and inspect HTML? How that button gets rendered?

Comment: Have you looked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504498/special-characters-in-extjs4 - looks like it should work as is - if you encode them properly in the file itself...

Comment: Yes, but since I have get the correct view in other project without '**encoding special character**', I have said that the framework take care of those special char ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution that I have chosen is to use HTML special character code as it is discribed in the post given by @sha :[stackoverflow.com/questions/...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504498/special-characters-in-extjs4) .

in the other hand I was looking for if Ext JS gives automatically the possibility of using spercial char.

Special thanks to @sha.